# python split and get correct value in for cycle

Tags: python

Hi i have issue with get currect value always in for cycle.
I got string like this. `test1,test2,test3,test4` string can be just `test1` or `test1,test2` (string size can be different) but always they will be separate with `,` .

So my code in python

```
 lst = groupFilter.split(",")
        for allFilter in range(len(lst)):
            if len(lst) is 1:
                 test = groupFilter.split(",")
                 print("This is if is one element in string")
            else:     
                test = groupFilter.split(",")[:-allFilter]
                print("This is if more than one")
```

like you see i try remove list by cut last element, or last 2 elements or last 3 elements but i understand it just leaving only first element not help with my issue..

For example cycle  wheels spin

For first time pick first, (for example `test1`)

For second time pick second (for example `test2`)

For third time pick third ( for example `test3`)

And its like what until the cycle stops

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just want:

```
for element in groupFilter.split(",")
    # do thing with element
```

This will cycle through each element (`test1`, `test2`, and so on).

Comment: thank you, i havo one more simple question, if i want do variable like ```SetSring``` and wanna make same string but with for cycle, it will be something like this ?  ```SetSring=SetSring +'' " + element``` ?

Comment: If all you want to do is replace commas with spaces and then stick the result onto the variable `SetSring`, I wouldn't use a `for` loop at all.  `SetSring += groupFilter.replace(",", " ")`